# How to convert string date from database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a string date of "`July 14, 2018`" from MySQL database. I just want to convert it to `date` format because I think my query doesn't recognize it. I have this sample code below:

```
$res=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT SUM(price) as INCOME,DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m',trans_date) as Date
                        from transactions where status='Paid' 
                        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m', trans_date)");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $income = $row['INCOME'];
    $date = $row['Date'];

    $formattedincome = number_format($income, 2)."<br>";
    echo "₱".$formattedincome;
    echo $date;
}
```

When I tried to run the query on `phpmyadmin`, the `Date` column was `NULL`.

[image]

Hope it is possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would have to ask why are you storing a date on the database in a string and not in a DATE column.

Comment: Its null because you cannot use `DATE_FORMAT` on a non-DATE type field. Since you said its just a string (assuming varchar?).

Comment: I stored the date first in a `SESSION` variable to use on other page. Then on that page, the insertion will happen. I stored it like this: `$_SESSION[datenow] = date('F j, Y');`